# How to get a ACCESS_TOKEN in splitwise

Tags: web-applications, access-token

I'm new make apps, now I'm working with splitwise and I just create an app.

The splitwise server give me:

Consumer Key
Consumer Secret
Token URL
and Authorize URL

But I Don´t know how to get a ACCESS_TOKEN with this data.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @user2533184 you can use nodejs to install the splitwise first using yarn command.

Step 1:

```
yarn add splitwise
```

Step 2:

```
const Splitwise = require('splitwise');
const sw = Splitwise({
  consumerKey: 'ConsumerKey',
  consumerSecret: 'ConsumerSecret'
})
```

And thats all you have to do.

and after that to access your username you can do:

```
sw.getCurrentUser().then(console.log)
```

The further Javascript API docs you can find at :
https://github.com/keriwarr/splitwise